# Creating a new user interactively on a remote machine

Tags: linux, ssh, terminal, account

I have function as such:

```
function accountSetup() {
ssh -tt $HOST << EOF
    adduser billy
    [second command]
    [third command]
EOF
}
```

Which **leaves the terminal hanging**. I have had success using the `-tt` flag previously to execute a few commands with `EOF` interactively, but I can't seem to create a new account interactively on my remote server with the above script.

This works fine, allowing me to set a password, name, etc. :

```
function accountSetup() {
    ssh -tt $HOST adduser billy
}
```

BUT, when I introduce my other necessary commands it starts getting dumb.. I'm sure there is a better way to execute them without repeatedly logging in like this:

```
function accountSetup() {
    ssh -tt $HOST adduser billy
    ssh -tt $HOST [third command]
    ssh -tt $HOST [second command]
}
```

**The Question**:
What is causing my terminal to hang in my first function? How can I ssh in once to create an account interactively and continue to execute commands?

Thanks :)

Comment: What are the second and third commands? Specifically, do they launch a process which keeps running after the ssh session is supposed to close?

Comment: Hi Kenster, simple things.. eg. add user to a group, check status of ufw. The only interactive element is adding a new user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you tell `ssh` to take its input from a heredoc, it cannot simultaneously take input from you via tty.

You can rewrite your commands as:

```
function accountSetup() {
    ssh -t $HOST '
        adduser billy
        [second command]
        [third command]
    '
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This allowed me to interactively execute multiple commands and keep the syntax readable.